# null в полях помеченных как @Autowired при попытке использования в spring-quartz Job?

Tags: java, spring, quartz

В приложении на spring использую связку spring-batch и spring-quartz

у меня есть сервис, который запускает задачу spring-batch. Название сервиса MyService, метод helloMethod();

```
@Service
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    Job processExportJob;

    public void helloMethod() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(processExportJob, jobParameters);
    }
}
```

Этот сервис запускается с помощью spring-quartz, который запускает по расписанию джобу. MyJob работает нормально если использовать только вывод в консоль. 
Далее я с помощью аннотации @Autowired внедряю свой сервис в джобу и она отрабатывает ровно один раз. Во все последующие разы, в поле service - null
Более того, если создать сервис не средствами spring'a,

```
MyService service  = new MyService();
```

То уже внутри сервиса все поля будут null, как мне это побороть?

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
public class MyJob implements Job {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
    private static final String MESSAGE = "===================================QUARTZ TACT===================================";
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, MESSAGE);
        try {
            service.helloMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, " Failed..");
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу на второй вопрос по поводу:

```
MyService service  = new MyService()
```

Здесь везде null потому как создавая обьект через new - вы создаете объект вне контекста, следовательно все сприговые аннтоации используемые в этом классе не сработают. Вместо этого вы можете сделать следующее:

```
@Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

А в методе, вместо MyService service  = new MyService():

```
MyService service = (MyService)applicationContext.getBean("MyService");
```

В принципе это эквивалент @Autowired над MyService, вот только если вы получите NPE для ApplicationContext, то вероятнее всего ваша проблема конфигурации quartz.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Я там накопал еще один момент, что после создания Job+Trigger+Scheduler(содержит все ссылки на всех) все это добро сериализуется. Причем поле job помечено как transient и в базу не пишется.
Видимо при срабатывании триггера, объект Job создается как-то через new

Comment: Нашел еще один рабочий способ

ApplicationContext springContext =
                    WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderListener.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getServletContext());

Object bean = springContext.getBean("meSerice");